# Styling a vanilla html table in react with a style-components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a regular HTML table in my app with the following structure (the values are not important):

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Header Row 1</th>
      <th>Header Row 2</th>
    </tr>
    {Object.values(someArray).map((value, index) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{value.1}</td>
          <td>{value.2}</td>
          <td>{value.3}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    })}
  </table>
```

I'm trying to solve the problem of having my `.css` rules being globally applied, as I want different tables to have different styling rules.

So I started to implement [`styled-components`](https://www.styled-components.com/). 
This is what I came up with

```
const CustomTable = styled.table`
  &&& {
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th,
    td,
    tr {
      padding: 5px;
    }
    th {
      text-align: left;
    }
    table {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
`;
```

Only the first grouping of rules seems to be applied to my table. So padding, text-align, and width doesn't seem to take effect. Is this a valid structure (grouping multiple elements that have multiple rules) or do I need to individually create styled-components for each table element (`<td>`, `<td>`, .. etc)?

Comment: [It works fine if you remove the `&&&`](https://codesandbox.io/s/9804oxyn94).

Comment: I didn't have the `<table>` tag inside the `<CustomTable>` styled component. Also the `width` is being set to 100% but that's not working still. I thought by doing: `const CustomTable = styled.table` it automatically wrapped, why do you still have to provide the `<table>` tag?

Comment: @Tholle If I set `<table style={{ tableLayout: "fixed" }}>` it works, not sure if that's the best way to do it, though. Trying to stick with `styled.components` and not be forced to do inline css.

Comment: I updated @Tholle's code : https://codesandbox.io/embed/pjrj8v48o7?fontsize=14
You shouldn't add additional `table` tag cause styled-component bring you.

Comment: @Deve that's interesting. So you can abstract the `table` css rules out of the nested rules. Is this somewhere in the docs? Feel free to post as an answer, I was going to, but your solution is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add global styles you can use`createGlobalStyle` from `styled-components` and use it to inject global styles to your components.

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components"
```

like this, I have updated @deve's code.[Codesandboxlink](https://codesandbox.io/s/ypvq1mvw59)